# Bucle infinito en programa para restar dos números armónicos

Tags: c++

Cuando intento ejecutar este programa que pide dos números n y m siendo n>m y crea el armónico de cada uno para luego restarlos y dar el resultado con diez decimales, me devuelve el error de "`execution error: time limit exceeded`". Lo he hecho para que no acabe mientras se le ingresen nuevos datos pero dentro de cada dato parece que hay un bucle que no localizo además de que los resultados no son los que debería.
Ej:

```
input: 3 2         Output: 3,3333333333 - tendría que ser 0,3333333333
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()  {
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(10);
    int n, m;
    while (cin >> n >> m) {
        double harmonic1 = 0.0;
        double harmonic2 = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            harmonic1 += 1./i;
        }
       for (int j = 1; j <= m; ++j) {
            harmonic1 += 1./j;
        }
        cout << harmonic1 - harmonic2 << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ese bucle que usas para obtener los datos de entrada, espera infinitamente a que estén disponibles ... ¿ seguro que ese el *protocolo* que debes seguir ?

Comment: Debe haber algo que no nos estás mostrando porque acabo de probar el código y funciona como dijiste pero no da error.

Comment: @Mateo desconozco por qué me ha dado ese error. Respecto a que no dé los números que debería, hay algún error en el planteamiento??

Comment: @Javocho `execution error: time limit exceeded` es un error habitual en los compiladores online, usa un compilador local.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster y dejando eso de lado, por qué el resultado es erróneo?

Comment: No sé qué son los armónicos ni cómo se calculan, ejecutando el código que provees con la entrada que provees efectivamente resulta en `3.3333333333` así que el problema está en el algoritmo.